# Laravel 5 won't logout user randomly

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, session, laravel-5

In my Laravel 5 app when I try to logout of the session, sometimes the logout only "refresh" the page, I have already tried almost everything.

My logout code is the default one:

```
public function getLogout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    Session::flush();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Could it be the timed ajax request for updating the notifications? The timer runs 10 in 10 sec... I already tried this code to stop all requests when I click in logout:

```
//Handle logout
$(document).on('click', "#logout", function(event){
    for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++)
        window.clearInterval(i);
});
$.xhrPool = [];
$.xhrPool.abortAll = function() {
    $(this).each(function(idx, jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.abort();
    });
    $.xhrPool = [];
};

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
        $.xhrPool.push(jqXHR);
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR) {
        var index = $.xhrPool.indexOf(jqXHR);
        if (index > -1) {
            $.xhrPool.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

What else can it be?

EDIT:

Ajax timer code:

```
setInterval(function(){
      $.ajax({
            url: '/notification/update',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                last: last
            },
            success: function (response) {
               //does something
            }
    });
},10000);
```

Logout:

```
<a href="{{URL::route('root') . '/user/logout'}}" id="logout"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>
```

This button send to the route that calls the first logout function, I don't get it why sometimes only refresh the page.

Comment: Wow. Why are you using such loop? You can store the returned ID of `setInterval` function.

Comment: Nevertheless, that doesn't explain why doesn't logout, I know that the loop is not necessary, but it was for a test and it didn't work...

Comment: Well, the redirection happens on the server. You need to change the location of the window manually using `location.href` property in JavaScript after logout. However, I'm not sure where you send the logout request in your JavaScript code.

Comment: I did this `$(document).on('click', "#logout", function(event){
    for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++)
        window.clearInterval(i);
    window.location.replace("/");
});` and it didn't work.

Comment: There is no need to clear an interval on redirection. Note that your current logout handler doesn't send any request, so how is it supposed to log out the user?

Comment: Yes it does, I didn't put that code because I though it would be easy to guess.
`<a href="{{URL::route('root') . '/user/logout'}}" id="logout"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>`